# PHP Append all URLs in RSS feed

Tags: php, string, rss, replace, append

I am trying to append all urls in a RSS feed with a extra string (like "/testing123" etc). The original url format from the RSS looks like this:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://website.com/item/name1/2162561"/>
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://website.com/item/name2/2162435"/>
```

etc, I used regexp with str_replace in a for loop but i cannot seem to get it working correctly and if i use preg_replace i get errors. When i just echo out the urls with the string appended it appears how i want but when i use str_replace then the urls looks like this instead:

```
http://website.com/testing123/item/name1/2162561
http://website.com/testing123/item/name2/2162435
```

I need the urls with the append string at the end when they get replaced however like this:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://website.com/item/name1/2162561/testing123"/>
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://website.com/item/name2/2162435/testing123"/>
```

The code i have is:

```
<?php 

// The append string
$append = '/testing123';

// The file
$file = "RSS.txt";

// Get the files contents
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

// The search pattern
$SearchPattern = '/href=["|\'](.[^"|\']+)/i';

// Run preg_match_all to grab all the Matches
preg_match_all( $SearchPattern, $contents, $Matches );

// Check to see if we have at least 1 match
$MatchCount = count($Matches[0]);

// If there is more than 1 match then run a for loop
if ( $MatchCount > 0 ) {
     for ( $i=0; $i < $MatchCount ; $i++ ) {

          $temp = $Matches[0][$i];
          echo $temp . $append . '<br />'; // Appears to work

          //$contents = str_replace($temp, $temp . $append, $contents); // But str_replace doesn't seem to work

          //preg_replace($temp, $temp . $append, $contents); // And using preg_replace gives a error

     };
};

echo $contents; // Display the contents

?>
```

Comment: Your original snippet seems to work fine.

Comment: No, it is placing the append string after website.com but it needs to go at the end of the URL instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
<?php 

// The append string
$append = '/testing123';

// The file
$file = "RSS.txt";

// Get the files contents
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

// The search pattern
$SearchPattern = '/(<link .* href=".*)("\/>)/i';

// Run preg_match_all to grab all the Matches
preg_match_all( $SearchPattern, $contents, $matches );

for($i=0;$i<count($matches[1]);$i++){
    echo $matches[1][$i].$append.$matches[2][$i]."\n";
}

?>
```

Basically, it filters the lines with regular expressions and extracts both sides of the index where you want to append text.

It then concatenates it all.

Comment: Thanks this was what i needed with some modification to make it replace the originals urls. The final change i made was for($i=0;$i<count($matches[1]);$i++){

 $temp = $matches[0][$i];
 $contents = str_replace($temp, $matches[1][$i].$append.$matches[2][$i], $contents);

}

echo $contents;

Answer (score 2):

Instead of preg matching/replacing, you could use **XPath** and **DOMDocument**

```
$html = <<< EOF
<xml>
  <items>
    <item>
      <link href="/testing/123" />
      <link href="http://test" />
      <font><tag>x</tag></font>
    </item>
  </items>
</xml>
EOF;
```

Example XML is absurd, of course. Code below checks for relative links, and makes them absolute.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadXML( $html );
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc );

$links = $xpath->query( "//link" );
for( $i = 0; $i < $links->length; $i++ ) {
    $href = $links->item($i)->getAttribute( 'href' );
    if( substr($href, 0, 4) != 'http' ) { 
        $links->item($i)->setAttribute( 'href', "http://" . ltrim($href, '/') );
    }
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

That spits out transformed HTML:

```
<xml>
<items>
<item>
<link href="http://testing/123">
<link href="http://test">
<font><tag>x</tag></font>
</item>
</items>
</xml>
```

Comment: I just found the answer i needed with the code from Florian F but thanks for your post.

Answer (score 1):

you need another variable to hold an array of $temp.

so

$match[i] =  $temp . $append;

then echo $match later (in a for loop or for each loop)

Or keep match as a string and append the 
 as well

```
// If there is more than 1 match then run a for loop

if ( $MatchCount > 0 ) {
     for ( $i=0; $i < $MatchCount ; $i++ ) {

          $temp = $Matches[0][$i];
          $match .= $temp . $append . '<br />'; // Appears to work

          //$contents = str_replace($temp, $temp . $append, $contents); // But str_replace doesn't seem to work

          //preg_replace($temp, $temp . $append, $contents); // And using preg_replace gives a error

     };
};

echo $match; // Display the contents

?>
```

Comment: I don't follow sorry, $temp = $Matches[0][$i];
    $match[i] = $temp . $append;
    echo $match; in the loop seems to give a error

Comment: Your not saving just the part you want. Your instead replacing and echoing the total. Dont echo it, just assign it to a variable thats outside of the scope

Comment: Thanks but when using your code it only outputs 1 url with href=" before it, there should be many urls however.

Comment: Sorry, Missed the .     try it again

Comment: The code you give seems to be doing what i had above where the append string is not at the end of the url - // Define $match variable
$match = "";

// If there is more than 1 match then run a for loop
if ( $MatchCount > 0 ) {
     for ( $i=0; $i < $MatchCount ; $i++ ) {

          $temp = $Matches[0][$i];
          $match .= $temp . $append; // Appears to work

          $contents = str_replace($temp, $match, $contents); 

     };
};

echo $contents; // Display the contents